# Check if String is more then 60% uppercase

Tags: java, string, percentage, uppercase

My question is simple: How to check if a String is more then 60% uppercase?

Comment: With a loop and using `myString.charAt()`

Comment: Please show the code you already have and tell us what issues you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
int uppers = 0;
for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if(Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        ++uppers;
    }
}
double pct = (uppers * 1D) / (s.length() * 1D) * 100D;
if(pct > 60D) {
   // do somnething
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Iterate through the string and count every uppercase character. Then divide this value by the string length.

Comment: This is the generally correct approach, although AIUI determining "uppercase" can get gnarly if you move outside common alphabets.

Comment: What if the string has spaces? What if it has non-latin-alphabetic characters?

Comment: You may need to also count the lowercase characters, depending on how you define 60%. Is it 60% of all characters, or 60% of alpha characters. If the latter, then the percentage would be #upper / (#upper + #lower)

Comment: @blgt The person writing the code needs to decide - or have clarified - the rules for themselves at that point. They aren't covered in the question (because it's pretty low quality).

Comment: this answer is as accurate as question is, correct approach

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do it. Not tested at all.

```
public boolean getPercentUpperCase(String str, int morethenpercent) {    
    int lowercaseChars = 0, uppercaseChars = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i >= str.length() -1; i++) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) {
            uppercaseChars++;
        } else {
            lowercaseChars++;
        }
    }

    return (Math.round(uppercaseChars / lowercaseChars) > morethenpercent);
}
```

Comment: You can improve that using a `while` which will stop when `uppercaseChars` is greater than `str.length * 0.6` (and also can stop after iterrating over all).
And you do not need lowerCaseChars since lowercasechars should be considerated like `str.length - uppercaseChars`.

Comment: Im not sure if it's really an improvement calculating every time if it's higher then, instead of counting if it's an uppercase

Comment: It will be an improvement. But insignificant since, I think, its String will not be a giant String.

Comment: But, why `i--` ? It makes no sense!

Comment: doesnt matter if increasing or decreasing. anywy, changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String test="AvCFrB";
char[] arr = test.toCharArray();
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    boolean upperCase = Character.isUpperCase(arr[i]);
    System.out.println(arr[i]+"="+upperCase);

    if(upperCase)
        count++;

}

double percentage = (count*1.0/test.length()*1.0)*100;
System.out.println(percentage);
```

Output-

```
A=true
v=false
C=true
F=true
r=false
B=true
66.66666666666666
```

Answer (score 0):

It is completely  based on programming and maths. It will be better you program this your self. However you can follow the below process.

1. get String size
2. check all the characters of string
3. count each upper case
4. apply the formula (100*total_uppercharecters)/string _size

Answer (score 0):

I give my solution right here which looks like some other but with some improvement I think. 
You can try my solution here: https://ideone.com/KGmMDa .

Note that I use `while` loop since I do not like `break`:

```
int upCount = 0;
int index = 0;
double percentLimit = str.length() * 0.6;
boolean upper = false;
while (!upper && (index < str.length())) {
    if(Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(index))) {
        upCount++;
        upper = upCount >= percentLimit;
    }
    index++;
}
return upper;
```

Grrr, here is with `for` and `break`, but I hate `break` :(

```
int upCount = 0;
double percentLimit = str.length() * 0.6;
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if(Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        upCount++;
        if (upCount >= percentLimit) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
return (upCount >= percentLimit);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the stream API in java 8 to achieve this.

```
public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(is60PercentUpper("aBc GH")); //true
    }

    public static boolean is60PercentUpper(String s){
    return s.chars()
            .filter(Character::isLetter)
            .map(entry -> Character.isUpperCase(entry) ? 1 : 0)
            .summaryStatistics()
            .getAverage() >= 0.60;
    }
}
```

What it does is:

- get a stream of chars from the string
- filter each char to only get letters
- map each char value to 1 if its in uppercase otherwise 0
- get the summary statistics and check if the average is superior or equals to 60%